# How to use caching using Zend 2 Module AssetManager?

Tags: zend-framework2

I was able to minify a CSS file with the following code block using Zend 2 Module AssetManager ([link](https://github.com/RWOverdijk/AssetManager)) but have a problem with caching. How do I configure it to cache the CSS file?

I see a HTTP status with 200 OK for the CSS file in Firebug. If the CSS file is cached, it should be 304 Not Modified.

Note that the Apache web server has read and write permissions for "public" directory and anything inside of the directory.

```
'asset_manager' => array(
    'resolver_configs' => array(
        'paths' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../public'
        )
    ),
    'filters' => array(
        'css/a.css' => array(
            array(
                'filter' => 'UglifyCss'
            )
        )
    ),
    'caching' => array(
        'a.css' => array(
            'cache' => 'FilePath',
            'options' => array(
                'dir' => __DIR__ . '/../public'
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the CSS file is cached, it should be 304 Not Modified.

No, it should only be a 304 if you configured browser caching in youre configuration. If you configure browser caching in the AsseticModule it only meens that the minified and combined css/js files are cached on youre system and not generated on every request.

Put something like this in youre .htaccess under public folder.

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Expires headers (for better cache control)
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    # Mod aktivieren
    ExpiresActive on

    # Standard Cache
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 minute"

    # Media
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 minute"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 minute"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 minute"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 minute"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 minute"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 minute"
</IfModule>
```